# Como ajustar um editor de texto personalizado para versão mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Existe alguma maneira de ajustar um editor na tela, na versão mobile, sem utilizar o css: `zoom:0.1` ou `transform:scale(0.1)`. Preciso fazer com que o elemento do CSS: `.main{}` que é CSS do container de todo o editor, se ajuste na tela do celular, porém quando utilizo os atributos de zoom ou scale do CSS3, ele perde totalmente a origem do rabisco da caneta do editor... Não sei o que estou fazendo errado... Pode ser em javascript, ou com alguma metatag de viewport, eu não sei como fazer isso rolar, eu já tentei fazer usando transform, e reajustando o plugin do editor passando novas coordenadas, porém ele não se adequa para todas as plataformas de tela, fica distorcendo muito... Alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O primeiro passo acho que seria mesmo colocar o `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` e ver como tudo vai se comportar. E a segunda coisa é colocar tudo em medidas de %, nada em valor fixo, e testar

Comment: Acredito que esses tipos de plugins não foram feitos para serem responsivos.